# jdbi BindBean userdefined property of the bean(nested object)

Tags: java, jdbi

I have a bean class

```
public class Group{string name;Type type; }
```

and another bean

```
public class Type{String name;}
```

Now, i want to bind group by using jdbi @BindBean

```
@SqlBatch("INSERT INTO (type_id,name) VALUES((SELECT id FROM type WHERE name=:m.type.name),:m.name)")
@BatchChunkSize(100)
int[] insertRewardGroup(@BindBean ("m") Set<Group> groups);
```

How can i bind the user defined object's property as member of the bean??

Answer (score 4):

You could implement [your own Bind-annotation](http://jdbi.org/sql_object_api_argument_binding/) here. I implemented one that I am adopting for this answer. It will unwrap all `Type` ones.

I think it could be made fully generic with a little more work.

Your code would look like this (please note that `m.type.name` changed to `m.type`):

```
@SqlBatch("INSERT ... WHERE name=:m.type),:m.name)")
@BatchChunkSize(100)
int[] insertRewardGroup(@BindTypeBean ("m") Set<Group> groups);
```

This would be the annotation:

```
@BindingAnnotation(BindTypeBean.SomethingBinderFactory.class)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ElementType.PARAMETER})
public @interface BindTypeBean {
    String value() default "___jdbi_bare___";

    public static class SomethingBinderFactory implements BinderFactory {
        public Binder build(Annotation annotation) {
            return new Binder<BindTypeBean, Object>() {
                public void bind(SQLStatement q, BindTypeBean bind, Object arg) {
                    final String prefix;
                    if ("___jdbi_bare___".equals(bind.value())) {
                        prefix = "";
                    } else {
                        prefix = bind.value() + ".";
                    }

                    try {
                        BeanInfo infos = Introspector.getBeanInfo(arg.getClass());
                        PropertyDescriptor[] props = infos.getPropertyDescriptors();
                        for (PropertyDescriptor prop : props) {
                            Method readMethod = prop.getReadMethod();
                            if (readMethod != null) {
                                Object r = readMethod.invoke(arg);
                                Class<?> c = readMethod.getReturnType();
                                if (prop.getName().equals("type") && r instanceof Type) {
                                    r = ((Type) r).getType();
                                    c = r.getClass();
                                }
                                q.dynamicBind(c, prefix + prop.getName(), r);
                            }
                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        throw new IllegalStateException("unable to bind bean properties", e);
                    }


                }
            };
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have already written a user defined bind annotation..Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Doing this in JDBI is not possible , you have to bring out the property and give is a argument.